# How to dismiss a certain view controller

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, view, dismiss

how can I dismiss a view controller beside the one that the user is currently in?

I need to replace self with the view controller name, but I get SIGABRT when I do so. What do I need to do? Thanks!

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
```

Comment: How is the view controller being presented?

Comment: ViewController *viewC = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil]; [self presentModalViewController:viewC animated:NO];

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
[self.parentViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: YES];
```