# How to dismiss a navigation controller?

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller, dismiss

I'm presenting a navigation controller (detailview) with showDetailViewController(). I want to dismiss it when a button is pressed. How can I dismiss this viewcontroller?

Code I've attempted:

```swift
//detailviewcontroller
    @objc
    func cancel(_ sender: Any) {
        print("cancelPressed")
        //self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
        //self.navigationController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        //self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        //splitViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        //splitViewController?.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
        //splitViewController?.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
        //splitViewController?.navigationController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        //navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
        //navigationController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        //self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
        //self.navigationController?.viewControllers.remove(at: 1)
        //self.navigationController?.viewControllers.remove(at: 0) - this one removes to blank view
        //self.presentingViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

I've tried multiple stackoverflow solutions:

[Dismissing a navigation view controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20471761/dismissing-a-navigation-view-controller)

[How to dismiss a view controller in a navigation controller, without dismissing the whole stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42889351/how-to-dismiss-a-view-controller-in-a-navigation-controller-without-dismissing)

[ios swift - dismiss root view controller of navigation controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36002219/ios-swift-dismiss-root-view-controller-of-navigation-controller)

[Can't dismiss View Controller that's embedded in a Navigation Controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54063449/cant-dismiss-view-controller-thats-embedded-in-a-navigation-controller)

[How to dismiss a navigation controller presented from another navigation controller in iOS 10 and below?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47267884/how-to-dismiss-a-navigation-controller-presented-from-another-navigation-control)

[Can't dismiss navigation controller in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31125017/cant-dismiss-navigation-controller-in-swift/31127779#31127779)

[Can't dismiss navigation controller in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31125017/cant-dismiss-navigation-controller-in-swift)

[Dismissing View Controller Doesn't Work While Using Navigation Controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51255265/dismissing-view-controller-doesnt-work-while-using-navigation-controller)

[Dismiss current navigation controller when clicked tab bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45648597/dismiss-current-navigation-controller-when-clicked-tab-bar)

[How to dismiss a certain view controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6969190/how-to-dismiss-a-certain-view-controller)

How I'm presenting the detailviewcontroller:

```swift
//masterviewcontroller
// delegation for passing data between controllers
weak var passDelegate: PlaceSelectionDelegate?

func insertNewObject(_ sender: Any) {
    if let detailViewController = passDelegate as? DetailViewController {
        if let detailNavigationController = detailViewController.navigationController {
            detailViewController.delegate = self
            splitViewController?.showDetailViewController(detailNavigationController, sender: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

Expected results:
dismiss detail viewController on button press.

Actual results:
No dismiss.

Comment: What should be visible in the detail side of the split view controller after dismissing the navigation controller?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've been looking for a way of dealing with this `showDetailViewController` for a while now and although I'm not sure this answers your question, this is how I did it:

I have two controllers, let's call it `FirstController` and `SecondController`. They both inherit from `UIViewController`. When I click a certain navbar button in the `FirstController`, I use `showDetailViewController` to show `SecondController` as a sheet moving upwards, like the "calendars" button in the Calendar app.

In `FirstController` I implemented 2 functions: one to show the `SecondController` and one to dismiss it. I call the dismiss action from within the `SecondController`. It looks like this:

```
// FirstController
@objc func showSecondView() {
    let vc = SecondController()
    vc.delegate = self          
    let nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController:vc)            
    self.showDetailViewController(nav, sender: self)
}

func closeSecondView() {
    self.dismiss(animated: true)
}
```

As you can see I wrapped my `SecondController` in a `UINavigationController`, so it shows the navbar with title and all. This is how the code looks like:

```
// SecondController
weak var delegate: FirstController!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    title = "Second"
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .done, target: self, action: #selector(closeMe))
}

@objc func closeMe() {
    delegate.closeSecondView()
}
```

Notice how I made a property for the `FirstController` and I use it to dismiss the `SecondController`. When I presented `SecondController` I assigned `self` as delegate, which means I can now call the `closeSecondView` method from within it.

I am not sure whether it works out of the box with split-view. The documentation seems to suggest that whenever you use it, if the screen is big enough, it behaves differently because `UISplitViewController` overrides it. It also says there that all view controllers have this method.

Take a look: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621432-showdetailviewcontroller

Give it a go, I hope this helps.

Answer (score -2):

This should work if you simply want to dismiss the navigation controller

```
navigationController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: This is in the list of failed attempts. In fact, it's in the list twice.

Comment: Is your navigationController not fixed yet ?